# Resource style xaml to c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have style resource in my button to make it rounded, and i want to create it using c#(code behind), how do i do it?

```
<Button.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
    </Style>
</Button.Resources>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem.  Style is a class.  You create it with `new Style()'

Comment: Yeah, but how do i apply style to button, if there's a way to apply not through resources, then i'd like to know

Comment: You may create a default Button Style in App.Resource with the Border Style in Style.Resources of the Button Style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create the `Style`:

   ```
    Style style = new Style() { TargetType = typeof(Border) };
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter() { Property = Border.CornerRadiusProperty, Value = new CornerRadius(5) });
    style.Seal();
   ```
2. Add it to the `Button`:

   ```
    button.Resources.Add(typeof(Border), style);
   ```

**XAML:**

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="..." />
```